# Advanced usage/command of shell

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any book , Tutorial on very very advanced shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12046/is-there-any-book-tutorial-on-very-very-advanced-shell-scripting)

Is there a way/book to learn advanced usage of shell by practice? I find that most shell programming books only teach you the grammar of shell script. Grammar is important but as in C programming the standard library is also important.

Comment: Have you looked at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12046/is-there-any-book-tutorial-on-very-very-advanced-shell-scripting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I've ever wanted to learn about the shell (BASH) can be found in Advance Bash Scripting Guide http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/. There are a myriad of examples here as well.

It includes all the sematics and information about the "standard library" you can find here http://www.gnu.org/manual/manual.html

Answer (score 0):

In bash doesn't exist a "standard library", only a basic functionality. So, yes, you can learn advanced usage by practice because the "standard library" is all the commands in your system (especially the coreutils).

Comment: *In bash doesn't exist a "standard library"* - Try typing `help`.

Comment: I used the quotes because this :) . So, the standard library in bash is the built-in (basic) functionality + the commands of the system.